# table cell spacing uneven

Tags: css, html

I am making an e-mail template, therefore I am restricted to using in line styling. The problem is that the social media links at the bottom won't get nice and even distance from each other. It looks bad. How can I get them to have even space in between? Thanks

Here's a fiddle, if you make the view wider like it is in an actual email it is more noticeable https://jsfiddle.net/89mnshyt/2/

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: Arial;">
     <div style="max-width: 80%; margin: auto;">
     <div style="max-width: 100%; margin: auto;">
    <a href="/"><img style="display: block; margin: auto;max-width: 300px;" src=""> </a> </div><br>
    <div>It was a pleasure doing business with you. Your thoughts mean a lot to us. Your reviews help us learn what we are doing well, what we need to work on, and what we can do to make your experience with our company even better. </div>
    
    <div> <span style="font-weight: bold;">Step 1: Follow the links or any (OR ALL!) of the review sites below </span><br><br> 
    Click the buttons below to go to that site and provide your review.</div>
    
    <div><span style="font-weight: bold;">Give us a rating and review. </span> <br><br>
    Choose a star rating and provide your comments.</div>
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">THANK YOU!</h3>
    <hr>
    <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
     <tr><td width="20%"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/jmH8Emc.jpg"><br> Google</a></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2UcUbJB.png" ><br> Yelp</a></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1ngaDhv.png" ><br> Facebook </a></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/y8BXkoK.jpg"><br> Car Gurus</a></td>
    
      <td width="25%"></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why not just add whitespace on the left & right of your images? That way they'll pad out the cells instead of the variable text width.

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa it got personal code wise haha. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: No problem, I've had to use special tricks like that when doing email campaigns over the years. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set each  to a 20% while first and last o 10%, or use align center on whole `<tr>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;">
 <div style="max-width: 80%; margin: auto;">
 <div style="max-width: 100%; margin: auto;">
<a href="/"><img style="display: block; margin: auto;max-width: 300px;" src=""> </a> </div><br>
<div>It was a pleasure doing business with you. Your thoughts mean a lot to us. Your reviews help us learn what we are doing well, what we need to work on, and what we can do to make your experience with our company even better. </div>

<div> <span style="font-weight: bold;">Step 1: Follow the links or any (OR ALL!) of the review sites below </span><br><br> 
Click the buttons below to go to that site and provide your review.</div>

<div><span style="font-weight: bold;">Give us a rating and review. </span> <br><br>
Choose a star rating and provide your comments.</div>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">THANK YOU!</h3>
<hr>


<table width="100%">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:10%;"></td>
  <td style="text-align: center; width:20%"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/jmH8Emc.jpg"><br> Google</a></td>
  <td style="text-align: center; width:20%"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2UcUbJB.png" ><br> Yelp</a></td>
  <td style="text-align: center; width:20%"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1ngaDhv.png" ><br> Facebook </a></td>
  <td style="text-align: center; width:20%"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/y8BXkoK.jpg"><br> Car Gurus</a></td>

  <td style="width:10%;"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <tr align="center">
        <td width="10" style="width:10px"></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/jmH8Emc.jpg"><br> Google</a></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2UcUbJB.png" ><br> Yelp</a></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1ngaDhv.png" ><br> Facebook </a></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/y8BXkoK.jpg"><br> Car Gurus</a></td>
        <td width="10" style="width:10px"></td>
   </tr>
```

try with this..

Answer (score 0):

You have set your table to 100%, but the individual  elements have no specified width.  You can do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;">
    <div style="max-width: 80%; margin: auto;">
    <div style="max-width: 100%; margin: auto;">
<a href="/"><img style="display: block; margin: auto;max-width: 300px;" src=""> </a> </div><br>
<div>It was a pleasure doing business with you. Your thoughts mean a lot to us. Your reviews help us learn what we are doing well, what we need to work on, and what we can do to make your experience with our company even better. </div>

<div> <span style="font-weight: bold;">Step 1: Follow the links or any (OR ALL!) of the review sites below </span><br><br> 
Click the buttons below to go to that site and provide your review.</div>

<div><span style="font-weight: bold;">Give us a rating and review. </span> <br><br>
Choose a star rating and provide your comments.</div>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">THANK YOU!</h3>
<hr>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>

        <td style="text-align: center;width:10%"></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width:20%"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/jmH8Emc.jpg"><br> Google</a></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width:20%"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2UcUbJB.png" ><br> Yelp</a></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width:20%"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1ngaDhv.png" ><br> Facebook </a></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width:20%"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/y8BXkoK.jpg"><br> Car Gurus</a></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width:10%"></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I have given the individual 's a width of 20%, and added 10% spacers on either end, as I suspect you tried to do.

Example here: https://jsbin.com/qoxabac/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you. There was the same answer before you though, so I marked that with the green tick. I upvoted this one, it should count and appear publicly when I have some more reputation.

Comment: Thank you! I’m glad you got help :)

Answer (score 0):

Be lazy, make your images do the work by making them wider and center the logos as part of the image:
https://jsfiddle.net/doc75ghq/

```
<td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/jmH8Emc.jpg"><br> Google</a></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2UcUbJB.png" ><br> Yelp</a></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1ngaDhv.png" ><br> Facebook </a></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/y8BXkoK.jpg"><br> Car Gurus</a></td>
```

No programming needed.